# opencv how can I select a region of image irregularly with mouse event? c/c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm learning opencv recently. Is there a way to select a region of image using mouse event? I already try out the triangle one. What if I want to choose a specific region but not a triangle shape? Thank you!

Comment: 1) There is no language C/C++. Only the distinct languages C and C++. 2) OpenCV uses now a C++ interface 3) Don't spam tags. 4) Read [ask], follow the advice. 4) What is your **specific** question? Where is the problematic code? 5) We are not a tutoring site.

Comment: Probably not. Open CV is a computer vision library, it has a few primitive GUI functions for displaying images to make development easier, but if you want a complex GUI operation, like allowing the mouse to describe an irregular region, you need to code it in a windowing system.

Comment: Register a callback to receive mouse-clicks. Save the clicked points in a vector of points. Draw a polygon with the points when you get a double-click. Make an ROI from the polygon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a little attempt at this - it is probably not the cleanest code, but should give you some ideas.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

// Globals
bool finished=false;
Mat img,ROI;
vector<Point> vertices;

void
CallBackFunc(int event,int x,int y,int flags,void* userdata)
{
   if(event==EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN){
      cout << "Right mouse button clicked at (" << x << ", " << y << ")" << endl;
      if(vertices.size()<2){
         cout << "You need a minimum of three points!" << endl;
         return;
      }
      // Close polygon
      line(img,vertices[vertices.size()-1],vertices[0],Scalar(0,0,0));

      // Mask is black with white where our ROI is
      Mat mask= Mat::zeros(img.rows,img.cols,CV_8UC1);
      vector<vector<Point>> pts{vertices};
      fillPoly(mask,pts,Scalar(255,255,255));
      img.copyTo(ROI,mask);
      finished=true;

      return;
   }
   if(event==EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN){
      cout << "Left mouse button clicked at (" << x << ", " << y << ")" << endl;
      if(vertices.size()==0){
         // First click - just draw point
         img.at<Vec3b>(x,y)=Vec3b(255,0,0);
      } else {
         // Second, or later click, draw line to previous vertex
         line(img,Point(x,y),vertices[vertices.size()-1],Scalar(0,0,0));
      }
      vertices.push_back(Point(x,y));
      return;
   }
}

int main()
{
   // Read image from file 
   img=imread("demo.jpg");

   // Check it loaded
   if(img.empty()) 
   { 
      cout << "Error loading the image" << endl;
      exit(1);
   }

   //Create a window
   namedWindow("ImageDisplay",1);

   // Register a mouse callback
   setMouseCallback("ImageDisplay",CallBackFunc,nullptr);

   // Main loop
   while(!finished){
      imshow("ImageDisplay",img);
      waitKey(50);
   }

   // Show results
   namedWindow("Result",1);
   imshow("Result",ROI);
   waitKey(5000);
}
```

[image]

---

### Explanation of the Callback

At the beginning of `main()` I do this:

```
setMouseCallback("ImageDisplay",CallBackFunc,nullptr);
```

and that tells **OpenCV** to call the function `CallBackFunc()` for us whenever the mouse moves or is clicked.

`CallBackFunc()` is just a normal function like any other function. However, we don't ever call it ourselves - **OpenCV** calls it for us asynchronously (when we aren't expecting it). Because of that, we can't see any returned value from the function - since we never called it - and that is why it is declared as:

```
void CallBackFunc(...)
```

because it returns nothing, or a void, or a dirty great void of nothingness.

Ok, let's move on to the parameters it is called with. Basically, when the designers of **OpenCV** wrote the `setMouseCallback()` function, they couldn't know what I would want to pass to it as a parameter - maybe I would want to pass a filename, maybe I would want to pass a text string to draw on the image when the mouse is clicked, maybe I would want to pass a variable that I wanted updated with the mouse position. It could be anything. So, as they didn't know, they decided to say it is a *"pointer to anything"* and I can use it for whatever I like. Well, nothing is anything, so a pointer to void can point to anything. So, they say just pass a pointer to void that you know the meaning of. Then, inside `CallBackFunc()` you can just cast the pointer to whatever it was you passed since you know what it is.

So, in summary a pointer to void is just a place-marker for a pointer to something and you can decide what that something is without the **OpenCV** designers needing to know.

Hope that helps!

Comment: wow! Thanks Mark! This is exactly what I'm looking for. I'll take a good look at it Thanks again man!

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!

But can you explain what mouse callback is exactly in c++ terms? I am still very confused about the static casts and void* that you have to use to call on the function.

Comment: I have added a little explanation at the bottom - hope it helps.