# display a specific contour by clicking on location in the image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

hi iam working on a project that require to display and isolate some contours to be reviewed and process for data extraction I want to assign and display a contour by click in its location in the image displayed by using the OpenCV library and python  language, I know I can get the location of the mouse in the image and get the mouse click event but I want also to display and remove contour when clicking the mouse

Comment: you can do two things, first associate with each contour some coordinates, then if these coordinates get clicked fetch and display the associated contour. Else you can try to find which contour is meant by tracking from the mouse coordinates to the closest contour (closest by some specirficed sense of distance, maybe more than one can match)

Comment: You can use a mouse callback - here is the C++ code, Python will be similar https://stackoverflow.com/a/42297587/2836621

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform your  contour into polygon and use  Opencv  point polygon test. 
https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/point_polygon_test/point_polygon_test.html