# Get the index of a point in a numpy array image by clicking on it

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to find a method where I can interact with an image (numpy array), and by clicking on a point on the image, it will return the index of that point in my array. Is this possible?

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

im = np.array(Image.open('purple_flowers_201054.jpg'))
plt.imshow(im)
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Personally, I would use **OpenCV** to display the image and register a mouse callback https://stackoverflow.com/a/42297587/2836621  but if you want to use `matplotlib` this looks like it may work for you... https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/users/event_handling.html

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you so much. Picking is nice but it just solved part of the problem. Because, the image looks 2D but is made from a 3D numpy array, I can't find the way to get the indices by using matplotlib pickling.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Sorry, I was wrong. It was a 2D numpy array