# Creating a virtual canvas in OpenCV2

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I was thinking of creating a shape matching program in Python using OpenCV2 where I have to give the input in a Paint-like console and it will be read by cv2.imread. But all I found on the internet was air canvas which is not exactly the thing I was looking for, rather a simpler version of that where I don't need to use the webcam and only a whitespace canvas.

I know a little about MouseCallback but it's fixed to a particular shape which needs to be predefined. Does anyone know how to build this virtual canvas where at least I can draw anything I want?

Comment: I don't understand you question very well but maybe something like this... https://stackoverflow.com/a/42297587/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell yeah quite like that, but it's too complicated for a code and I'm not that much of a professional in OpenCV. I just want an MS Paint like interface where I can draw any imaginary shapes I want, which will be read by OpenCV.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Surely you can draw your shapes with MS Paint, save as BMP and OpenCV can read them?

Comment: Yeah but it won't be a live one then. I want to make it in realtime @MarkSetchell