# Efficiently(Real time) display PIL Image in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Currently I writing a program that needs to allow user to draw simple lines, and also draw rectangles to select an area. I was using tkinter's canvas before, but that had performance with some operations and also memory leak, so I'm trying to use pillow to draw instead.

Here's my code for draw rectangle:

```python
  def drawRect(self, start, end):

        x1 = end[0]
        y1 = end[1]

        x0 = start[0]
        y0 = start[1]

        t0 = time()
        t = time()
        
        #size of image is roughly between 1000x1000 to 1080p
        rectLayer = Image.new("RGBA", self.backgroundImage.size)
        rectDraw = ImageDraw.Draw(rectLayer)
        rectDraw.rectangle([start, end], fill="#00000080")
        rectDraw.line((x0, y0, x1, y0, x1, y1, x0, y1, x0, y0), fill="#ffffff", width=1)
        print("drawing: ", time() - t)
        t = time()

        displayImage = Image.alpha_composite(self.backgroundImage, self.linesLayer)
        displayImage.alpha_composite(rectLayer, (0, 0), (0, 0))
        print("image blend: ", time() - t)
        t = time()

        self.photoImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(displayImage)
        print("photoImage convert: ", time() - t)
        t = time()

        self.imageContainer.configure(image=self.photoImage)  # imageContainer is a Label
        print("label config: ", time() - t)
        print("total: ", time() - t0)

'''
Output for drawing a single rect:

    drawing:  0.001994609832763672
    image blend:  0.009583711624145508
    photoImage convert:  0.0139617919921875
    label config:  0.02194380760192871
    total:  0.049475669860839844
'''
```

The issue I'm facing is that although PIL is fast, displaying that image is not. From my time profiling, drawing the rectangle took very little time, but converting the image to photoimage, then setting it as the image of a label took a long time. I was hoping that this functions can run at least 60 times or so per second, so that the program feels smoother to use. Is there a way I can display images quicker?

Comment: If you need performance, then you need to take `tkinter` and throw it into the nearest trash can.  Tkinter has ALWAYS been a hack.  You may not be aware, tkinter is a library written in a language called tcl.  Python has to run its own tcl interpreter inside the Python interpreter/  Everything you do in tkinter ends up launching a command in the tcl interpreter.  Toss it out and use a real UI library, like wxPython or Qt.  If all you need is images, even OpenCV could do that.

Comment: The canvas doesn't have a memory leak. What do you mean by _"I was using tkinter's canvas before, but that had performance with some operations and also memory leak"_?

Comment: @BryanOakley Maybe my understanding of memory leak is not correct :p 
From my understanding, when a drawn object is deleted from the canvas, the canvas doesn't release the memory that object used to hold. Also, another issue I had with canvas is that after drawing many lines, modifying existing lines takes a long time(such as scaling the whole canvas).

Comment: Ok. The objects are freed, but the identifiers are not reused, so yes, if you keep creating and deleting objects instead of reusing the identifiers you'll eventually run out of identifiers.

Comment: @TimRoberts: tkinter is more than sufficient for a very large variety of tasks. While it's not up to the task of making a new version of photoshop or doom, it works extremely well for what most people need. Tkinter is indeed a real UI library, designed from the beginning to be embedded in other products.

Comment: You can use `self.photoImage.paste(displayImage)` to replace `self.photoImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(...)` and `self.imageContainer.configure(...)`.

Comment: @BryanOakley I disagree.  Tk is 30 years old, and it shows that ancient legacy.  Because it's built on the equally ancient tcl, it can't move forward.  It encourages poor programming practices.  It's only in Python because there were no alternatives at the time.  Now, there are alternatives.

Comment: @acw1668 .paste(displayImage) was slightly better(0.025 sec) since it takes 1 less tcl call

Comment: @BryanOakley what would you recommend for my use case then? For tkinter canvas, reusing identifier seems okay for drawing squares, but when I need to modify all the lines, for example when changing canvas size, or need to toggle line visibility. For a canvas with a reasonable amount of scribble on it, modifying lines starts to take a long time(~half a second). Now when I changed to render lines with PIL, Im bottlenecked by photoimage and setting image to label. Perhaps a simple paint program in tkinter is not viable?

Comment: Not certain what you are trying to do precisely, but maybe you could use **OpenCV** with callbacks to draw like I did here - I know it is `C` but there is a direct equivalent in Python if the concept works https://stackoverflow.com/a/42297587/2836621

Comment: @TimRoberts Hi Tim. Would you be able to name some of the better alternatives you allude to please? Thanks.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I did so, in my original comment.

Comment: @TimRoberts Ah, ok, I see what you were saying now. Thank you.