# Trace mouse path using ImageMagick?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I'm using Imagemagick to alter images (crop, rotate and the like) - and I've been finding a lot of success using it by digging through their documentation.

One thing I'm having trouble with is finding the correct way to draw a free-form mouse path on top of the particular image. I haven't been able to find any examples of anybody doing that in any of the documentation (for reference, I've been reading [this](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/)).

Has anybody done this before or should I be using a different utility to accomplish what I want to do?

Comment: I would guess you need to use a Java/JavaScript method.

Comment: ImageMagick is a command line tool. It is not an interactive one for the most part. So you need some other tool to do interactive drawing.

Comment: I am unaware of any mouse integration whatsoever within **ImageMagick** itself. You could fairly easily make mouse trails with **tkinter** or with **OpenCV** in Python or C++, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42297587/2836621