# Interactive numpy image - is it possible?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, image-processing

I have a 2D numpy array (image) which I visualise using plt.imshow().

What I want: a user to be able to click on a given pixel on this image (matrix/2D array) and the indices of this particular element to be saved as variables - for example i = 200 and j = 150.

The end goal is for the user to be able to crop a part of the image for further processing of this part of the array.

If anyone knows how to apply a region of interest (by dragging the mouse along the image/2D array), even better.

Comment: is plt the matplotlib.pyplot library?

Comment: Here's an idea... https://stackoverflow.com/a/42297587/2836621

Comment: I think OP wants a Python solution. But he didn't attempt to provide any example of code.

Comment: OpenCV code is always the same. translation from C++ to python has all the same APIs. -- I would suggest doing this with just OpenCV, no matplotlib. use `cv.selectROI`