# Dynamic plotting pixels on screen in Python

Tags: python, pixel

I am developing a relatively simple program in Python to allow students to explore recurrence relations of the form x(n+1)  = (1+b)F(xn) – bx(n-1).  The results are ‘dust’ type fractals based on work by Gumowski and Mira.  Each iteration of the function generates a single (x,y) point

The code generating iterations is relatively trivial.  However, as a newcomer to Python I am looking for the most efficient method that enables students to see how the iterations (orbits) evolve on screen, iteration by iteration, pixel by pixel.

I have looked at Pillow and matplotlib but neither option provides the dynamic display I am looking for.  The code extract below (without additional user interface details) shows an example using matplotlib.  A friend has suggested using Pygame but commented that it can be quite slow to update for large numbers of pixels.

Does anyone have any better suggestions for a non-expert solution before I investigate using Pygame gfx?

```
#mira exmple using matplotlib to visualise static result
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#initialise base parameters
a = 0.5
b = 0.998

#set starting point
x = 0
y = 12.1

#set level of iterations
p = 10000

#initialise arrays for holding x , y results
x_plot = [0]
y_plot = [12.1]

#define f(x) and generate initial value
f = (a*x + ((2-2*a)*x**2))/(1+x**2)

for n in range(1000,p):
    z = x
    x = b*y + f
    f = (a*x + ((2-2*a)*x**2))/(1+x**2)
    y = f - z

    x_plot.append(x)
    y_plot.append(y)

plt.style.use('classic')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x_plot, y_plot, s = 1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: **OpenCV** provides `cv2.imshow()` which can very simply display an image held in a Numpy array. It can also display and read sliders and get mouse clicks. Quick idea here in C++ though Python is pretty similar https://stackoverflow.com/a/42297587/2836621

Answer (score 0):

i think `pygame` should work fine, if you generate the frames correctly.
Alternatively you could give `jupyter notebooks` and [Jupyter Widgets](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) a shot.

Comment: Thanks bsatprivat - looks like I need to investigate  pygame in detail